# Storing ASIHttpRequest PDF as NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have a pdf which I am trying to store temporary in memory, and give option to the user if s/he wants to save the pdf to iPhone. I am using Asihttprequest to talk to the server, therefore I am just curious, what is the best way to setDownloaddestination as nsdata?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used ASIHTTPRequest, however does this from the documentation solve your answer?

> Downloading the response directly to a file
>
> If the resource you are requesting is fairly large, you can save memory by downloading
> directly to a file. This way, ASIHTTPRequest won’t have to keep the whole response in
> memory at once.
>
> ```
> ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
> [request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/my_file.txt"];
> ```

Came from about 20% of the way down http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use.

Comment: Greg, the thing is, I don't want to initially download the file but rather capture in nsdata. I do happen to get the file however when pushing in webView, my content tends to be just white pdf, as I do notice nsdata does have the data when viewing the description.

Comment: Ah, okay.. so you have a PDF already in an NSData object? If so, would NSData's [writeToFile](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIAEAHFJ) then let you save that object to a local file?

Comment: Greg, thanks for the help, I got it working now. I happen to store the response body into nsdata initially and then load it webview.